# how to find Vc(t) and Vo(t)?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: OP-AMP]
I tried to calculate Vc(t) and Vo(t), but I got insensible value
Can any one HELP me and give me a key?

Answer (score 1):

As much as i can see is that after t>0, the current is is going to be zero because

u(t) = 1 , t>0

so u can take a hint from this.

Comment: If u found it helpful please mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

First thing when dealing with this type of circuit is what my teachers called "the triple zero rule": on the op-amp, both input current are zero and the voltage between inputs is zero.

Now try to begin with current relation on nodes and voltage relation on the grid.
Here let's call R1 th 4 ohms resistor and R2  the 6ohms one, ic is the current flowing from left to right in the capacitor and ir the current flowing from left to right in R1.

We have:

is = ic+ir

ic = C dVc/dt + Vc(0)

ir = Vc/R1 = Vo/R2  which lead you to Vo=Vc.R2/R1

So you have:

is = C dVc/dt + Vc(0) + Vc/R1

To find Vc(0), we suppose that the capacitor has reached a static state so ic=0 which lead to Vc(0) = is(0)R1. is(0) is 1 amp just before t=0 so Vc(0) = R1

Then you have here a differential equation to solve to get Vc then Vo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

At \$t = 0^-\$, \$ I_s = 1 A\$.

Since it is DC, no current flows through C. Entire current flows through the resistors.

So you can find the voltage at non-inverting terminal of op-amp. Since op-amp is acting as [voltage follower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_amplifier#Op-amp_implementation), \$V_o(0^-)\$ = voltage at non-inverting terminal. Then \$V_c(0^-)\$ can also be calculated.

At \$t = 0\$, the current source turns off. So it is open circuited. Then the capacitor starts to discharge from \$V_c(0^-)\$ to 0 through resistors. So the voltage across capacitor can be expressed as the standard [discharge equation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/151570/27943).
 $$Vc(t) = V_c(0^-)\times e^{-t/RC}$$

\$V_o\$ will be equal to voltage at non-inverting terminal of amplifier. And voltage at non-inverting amplifier will be given by [voltage divider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) formed of the two resistors.

$$V_o(t) = V_c(t) \times \mathrm{(voltage\ division\ factor) }$$